# What is wrong with this perl regular expression?

Tags: regex, perl

I'm trying to go through a file, and only print out words without a specific letter, specified in a character class.

```
 if ( $+ =~ [^Aa] )
{
print $_;
}
```

But this doesn't work. What am I doing wrong? The above example should give back a list of words without 'a' or 'A' in them, but it doesn't seem to be working.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The regular expression says "Include a character that is not A or a" not "Includes only characters that are not A or a".

It is also missing delimiters.

```
$+ =~ /^[^Aa]*$/
```

or

```
$+ !~ /[Aa]/
```

Comment: or `$+ =~ /[^Aa]/` or even perhaps `$+ !~ /a/i`